# I get a black strip when taking pictures with Canon EOS 760D. How can I fix it?

Tags: canon, repair

I was taking photos and suddenly a black strip appears on the pictures. Then I realized that something was wrong with the camera, some mechanism was not working.

There is something stuck when the picture is taken. When I set the on-camera viewer I can see a black band or belt blocking the light as you can see in the following image

Is there a way to fix this easily? (*I would be willing to un-mount the camera to check and repair it if someone guides me*).

Do you recommend that I send it to some technical service?

How much can it cost to fix the camera?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That appears to be part of your shutter mechanism. It's broken and needs to be replaced. That's probably beyond the ability of a DIYer since it pretty much requires complete disassembly of the camera and some specialized equipment to insure the sensor and lens mount flange are properly aligned when reassembled. Whether sending it out for repair is worth it or not depends on several variables.

Among them:

- The cost of the repair for the part of the world you are in. Repair costs can vary widely from one locale to the next.
- How much another used EOS 760D or similar camera would cost. The 760D/Rebel T6s was replaced by the 77D in 2017. Again, where you're located can affect that significantly.
- How much a newer camera with improvements over the 760D would cost relative to a repair or replacement. The 77D is still available new in kits with lenses, but apparently not as a body only option.

Comment: I found these parts on eBay, and they are relatively cheap: [Shutter Blade](https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Shutter-Blade-For-Canon-EOS-760D-Rebel-T6s-Repair-Part/264349955034?hash=item3d8c7c33da:g:URsAAOSw-olZ7xSl), [Original Shutter](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Original-Shutter-Assembly-Group-for-Canon-EOS-750D-EOS-760D-Camera-Repair-Part/303004409792?hash=item468c785fc0:g:vUMAAOSwNe9cHKw4). Do you think that the labour cost will be very expensive comparing to the part prices?

Comment: I think for most folks, trying to do this themselves will destroy the camera. All it takes is internally damaging one of the many flex cables that must be detached/reattached, or failing to put the variable thickness shims that are used to align the sensor with the lens flange back in the same position each one came off from, or any number of other things that a novice will be totally unaware that they need to be concerned with. Since you haven't told us where on the planet you are I have *no idea* what it might cost *you* to get a shutter replaced. Here in the U.S., I'd guess around $300...

Comment: ... for the EOS Rebel T6s, which is what the EOS 760D is called here. It can vary significantly based on the camera model. It also varies highly from one world area to the next. The cost to Canon of giving warranty for repairs can fluctuate based on the local consumer laws in force in various countries, as well as the cost of skilled labor for their technicians, etc.

Comment: If I were to attempt replacing a shutter myself, I'd buy a *new* complete shutter assembly with the blades already attached. Buying parts like you have linked to means they've likely been salvaged from a used camera and may be highly worn themselves. Presumably the blades came from a shutter assembly already used so much it failed, and the shutter assembly without blades almost certainly came from a camera with enough use that the blades failed in it. Canon doesn't even sell the shutter assembly without blades installed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comments :). I live in Spain, so I assume that the price it'll be quite similar to what you say. Anyway, I will try to check some price estimation with some technician close to where I live, in order to make a final decision.